# What does in ? operator/prefix in Erlang mean?

Tags: erlang

What does the question mark in **?MODULE** (which can be seen in all generated code by Mochiweb make command) mean?

```
-export([start/1, stop/0, loop/2]).

start(Options) ->
    {DocRoot, Options1} = get_option(docroot, Options),
       Loop = fun (Req) ->
               ?MODULE:loop(Req, DocRoot)
       end,
    mochiweb_http:start([{name, ?MODULE}, {loop, Loop} | Options1]).

stop() ->
    mochiweb_http:stop(?MODULE).

loop(Req, DocRoot) ->
    ...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It denotes [a preprocessor macro](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#id79937). `?MODULE` is one of the predefined macro constants that expand to current module's name.

Answer (score 10):

Well this is the way we represent MACROS in Erlang. At compile time, these macros are replaced with the actual meanings. They save on re-writing pieces of code or on abstracting out a parameter you may change in future without changing your code (would only require a re-compilation of the source that depends on the MACRO).

Forexample:

```
-module(square_plus).
-compile(export_all).
-define(SQUARE(X),X * X).

add_to_square(This,Number)-> ?SQUARE(This) + Number.
```

Is the same as:

```
-module(square_plus).
-compile(export_all).

add_to_square(This,Number)-> (This * This) + Number.
```

Answer (score 1):

-define(Macro,Replacement). is used by the preprocessor to supports macros to have more readable programs. It can be used to have a conditional compilation. It is recommended that If a macro is used in several modules, it's definition is placed in an include file.

A macro definition example:

```
-define(TIMEOUT, 200).
```

For using macro:

```
?TIMEOUT.
```

List of predefined macros:

```
?MODULE: The name of the current module.
?FILE: The file name of the current module.
?LINE: The current line number.
?MACHINE: The machine name.
```

Source: [https://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~amirg/tutorial/erlang/](https://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/%7Eamirg/tutorial/erlang/)